# Dynatrace Streaming Media Reporting In Android

Tags: javascript, android, video-streaming, report, dynatrace

I want to report Streaming Media in Android application as web client can easily do it by this doc:

https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DOCDT61/Streaming+Media

Web Client use JavaScript plugin to do it so, but Android platform has no JavaScript platform streaming videos.

So actually, I wonder if I can report Video Stream what exactly as web client do.

One example of Streaming Media Details from web client is below:
[image: Streaming Media Report From Web Client]

But when I send report from Android app, it appears like this:
[image: User Action Report From Android App]

I couldn't find any way to report Streaming Media as the first image in Android App in Dynatrace docs.

I'd be appreciated to hear your advices.